# Passing identically-named params to a Rspec POST request to create an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, parameters

I have an API call where I need to POST an array of IDs. I know that if I pass several params called `ids[]` to my request, they'll appear as an array in the `params` hash in the controller:

```
# POST /api/events
# params:
# ids[] = 1 
# ids[] = 2
# ids[] = 3


# Then in Api::EventsController:

puts params # => { ids: [ "1", "2", "3"] }
```

But how can I test this? I can't use the same parameter name twice in my RSpec test:

```
post "/api/events", :"ids[]" => 1, :"ids[]" => 2, :"ids[]" => 3
```

Because what that really means is:

```
post "/api/events", {:"ids[]" => 1, :"ids[]" => 2, :"ids[]" => 3}
```

... and hashes can't have the same key twice, so the second argument gets reduced to just `{:"ids[]" => 3}`.

And something like `:"ids[]" => "1,2,3"` doesn't work, it just results in `ids: ["1,2,3"]`.

What should I pass to the `post` method to get an array in the `params` hash of my controller?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

****Facepalm****

I don't know why this didn't occur to me, but you can just pass an array as one of the hash values:

```
post "/api/events", :ids => [1, 2, 3]
```

Guess I was taking the URL syntax a little bit too literally.

Hopefully this answer will save a future Googler 30 seconds.